# When is the correct time to call restoreState for QHeaderView?

Tags: c++, qt

Here's the problem:

Say we have a model, already loaded with data.

We attach this model to QTableView.

We check that tableView->horizontalHeader() exists.

We call ->restoreState on this headerview.

Nothing happens. Column sizes and positions stay the same.

Seems like Qt still needs to do some processing after model has been assigned to a view before restoreState can be called.

Above is my assumption because priming a timer and calling the func 100-200 ms later always works.

But if so, when is the correct time to call it and how to do it properly?

Comment: Some events goes through the window message loop. Id you tried to queue your signal?

Comment: How do I queue it? That's basically the main question. restoreState isn't a slot.

Comment: Any time I've used `QHeaderView::restoreState` it's been pretty much *immediately* before the event loop is entered (e.g. `QApplication::exec()`) and it's worked fine.  Can you update your question with some relevant code?  Are you sure the data you're restoring from is valid?